# How to only output words that start with "b" from an array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, for-loop

I have created a program that allows the user to enter 5 words. These words
are stored into a string array. When the user is finished, the number of times a word beginning with the letter ‘B’ was entered, lower or uppercase is displayed. Now I also have to re-state the B words.

So this is the code I have so far that finds how many of the words entered starts with "b"

```
int fromIndex = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String words[] = new String [5];

    for (int x = 0 ; x <= words.length - 1 ; x = x + 1)
    {
        System.out.print ("Please enter a word: ");
        words [x] = kbi.readLine ();
        fromIndex = 0;
        words [x] = words [x].toLowerCase ();


        fromIndex = words [x].indexOf ("b", fromIndex);
        if (fromIndex == 0) // STARTS WITH B
        {
            count++;

        }

    }

    System.out.println ("You entered " + count + " 'B' words and they were: ");
```

I was thinking that I could use an if statement to print the b words. Like:

```
if (words.charAt(0) == "b")
{
    System.out.println (words);
}
```

but that doesn't really seem to work and I didn't really think it would, I'm kind of at a loss of what to do.

I hope I can receive some help on this, thank you in advance.

Comment: `char` literals are enclosed in single quotes: `'b'`

Comment: could try `String::startsWith`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code words is not an String(it is an array of String) so it doesn't have charAt method that you used above. you have 5 String in your words array so if you want to write all String in your array which start with character 'b' you should loop through your array and print all that start with 'b', like this:

```
for(String str : words){
    if (str.charAt(0) == 'b'){
            System.out.println(str);
}
```

some tips:
in java 7 String has startsWith method that you can use. if you are using java 6 check if it  has it too:

```
for(String str : words){
        if (str.startsWith("b", 0)){
            System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `charAt` returns `char` instead of `String`, so you would have to change your comparison:

```
if (words.charAt(0) == 'b')
```

Other possibility would be to use regex `"b.*"` or even easier - `String` comes with `startsWith` method, so you can simply do this:

```
if (words.startsWith("b"))
```